# Jquery not selecting correct value on Chosen DropDownList

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I have a dropdown that is filled and is using the Chosen plughin.  When selected the value, not text, is needed to fill out the page.  I have tried a few different ways, but none seem to work.

**The markup:**

```
<select class="chzn-select" data-placeholder=" -- Select Course -- " id="CourseDropDown" name="CourseDropDown">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
</select>
```

**Things I have tried:**

```
$('#CourseDropDown').on('change', function () {
    var courseID = $(this).val();
....
    var courseID = $('#CourseDropDown').val();
....
    var courseID = $('#CourseDropDown :selected').val();
....
```

All of these return an empty string.

I am able to get the text from the selection by doing

```
var courseID = $(this).text();
```

The markup clearly has a value set for the selection. Its selecting the correct thing and returning the text.  What would cause it to return an empty string instead of the value 1.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. All of the above seem to return the value in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/dfqduznz/

Comment: your code works fine. check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L7rqusq4/. i guess you're selecting the first option in the dropdown which has an empty value

Comment: @Sushil It's not selecting the first one.  When I switch it to .text() it gives the correct options text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be from how I set up chosen.  All the info I found stated that in order to show the place holder within the drop down, like " -- Select Something -- ", you needed to prepend an empty value/option.  It seems that this value was overriding the options value even though the markup was correct and selecting the .text() worked.

I removed the prepended option.  It now works as it should and still displays the placeholder.

Answer (score 2):

the `.val()` works fine for me, here's a snippet https://jsfiddle.net/20kckhf9/